# Silverstripe subdomain 500 internal error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, silverstripe

I have installed silverstripe website inside root of `public_html` directory and in the some root directory i create subdomain via cPanel.
My subdomain is moodle app.

Before installing silverstripe everything work good now when i try to access moodle.mywebsite.com i get `500 Internal Server Error`.

Problem is in `.htaccess` how correct modify that file to allow access to `moodle` subdomain

Here is my ss `.htaccess`

```
### SILVERSTRIPE START ###
# Deny access to templates (but allow from localhost)
<Files *.ss>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>

# Deny access to IIS configuration
<Files web.config>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Files>

# Deny access to YAML configuration files which might include sensitive information
<Files *.yml>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

# Route errors to static pages automatically generated by SilverStripe
ErrorDocument 404 /assets/error-404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /assets/error-500.html

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    # Turn off index.php handling requests to the homepage fixes issue in apache >=2.4
    <IfModule mod_dir.c>
        DirectoryIndex disabled
    </IfModule>

    SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase '/'

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]


    # Deny access to potentially sensitive files and folders
    RewriteRule ^vendor(/|$) - [F,L,NC]
    RewriteRule silverstripe-cache(/|$) - [F,L,NC]
    RewriteRule composer\.(json|lock) - [F,L,NC]

    # Process through SilverStripe if no file with the requested name exists.
    # Pass through the original path as a query parameter, and retain the existing parameters.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule .* framework/main.php?url=%1 [QSA]
</IfModule>
### SILVERSTRIPE END ###
```

Also i try to create new `.htaccess` inside `moodle` subdomain directory and put this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
</IfModule>
```

Now i dont have `500 Internal Error` now i get list of all files listed and `index.php` is not executed like default

How to slove this my problem?

Comment: subdomain (moodle.example.com) or subfolder (example.com/moodle) ?

Comment: `moodle.example.com` ... Its sloved

Comment: You might show us your solution or just delete the question if it was something different and unrelated with silverstripe.

Comment: this question is not SilverStripe related, but about how to handle subdomains with single entry point (index.php). Some webhosting providers do not create proper vhosts for subdomains.

Comment: Problem is in SS how he route subdirectories. I slove problem view editing route and `.htaccess`